# Remove underline for an image inside a link - SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

How do I get rid of the underline for the image inside the link in SCSS. Could anyone please help?

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-frost-9xzrj?file=/index.html)

**HTML**

```
      <p>
        <a href="#">
          Link
          <span>
            <img src="imagePath" alt="logo" />
          </span>
        </a>
      </p>
```

**SCSS**

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
 &:hover{
border-bottom: 1px solid red
 }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the img to be clickable (as part of the anchor element innerHTML) but you don't want it to be underlined when the user hovers. Is that correct? Are you able to alter the HTML or do you want a CSS(SCSS) only solution?

Comment: The first one, want the image to be clickable but the underline should be only for the text. I won't be able to alter the html because it is plugged in via `[innerHtml]` in Angular. Appreciate if it is only SCSS solution. @AHaworth

Answer (score 1):

Try to put background color on span border-bottom:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
a:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
a:hover span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <a href="#">
      Link
      <span>
        <img
          width="10"
          src="https://bitsrc.imgix.net/3b69976526d31a20a1fd238f5a32a704cf437dd6.png"
          alt="logo"
        />
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm supposed to use only `border-bottom-color` :(

Comment: Ahh, ok, try now just put background color on span border, I updated answer

Comment: try putting `border-bottom-color:transparent` on the `<span>`

Answer (score 1):

As yiu can't alter the HTML, this snippet puts the underline on a pseudo element rather than on the actual element. The pseudo element is made to have the same width as the text ('Link') by using that as its content - which is slighly nasty as it means if the text of the Link changes the CSS/SCSS will also have to change.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover::before {
  content: 'Link';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#">
          Link
          <span>
            <img src="imagePath" alt="logo" />
          </span>
        </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll thats tricky and also not the best practices when it comes to frontend buuutt

Since you know the size of the image, you can add a fake border-bottom with the pseudo`:after` element with width 100% - [width-of-the-element]:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
    &:before{ // we initialize it before showing to avoid creating elements on interaction
        position:absolute;
        content:'';
        left:0;
        bottom:-2px;
        border-bottom:1px solid red;
        width:calc(100% - 10px - 0.2em); // the image is 10px and the space bar is ~0.2em
        display:block;
        opacity:0; // just some nice transitioning
        transition:all .5s ease;
    }
    &:hover{
        //border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        &:before{
            opacity:1;
        }
    }
}

<p>
    <a href="#">
        Link
        <span>
            <img
          width="10" src="https://bitsrc.imgix.net/3b69976526d31a20a1fd238f5a32a704cf437dd6.png" alt="logo"
            />
        </span>
    </a>
</p>
```

[Check here a working sample](https://codepen.io/teefars/pen/xxLVyOv)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to do it but here's one that doesn't change your HTML flow. Since the image is inside the `<a>` and the border is being applied to the `<a>`, you can move the img outside the bounds of the `<a>` with positioning so it doesn't affect the width of the element and thus the border.

```
a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;

  &:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  }

  img
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
  }
}
```

The `left` is to push it to the outside of the element on the right side, and the `padding-left` and `padding-top` are to put it in roughly the same position it was in your sandbox.

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hofstadter-14zim)

---

An alternative would be to wrap the text inside the `<a>` in their own element, like a span, and then apply the border just to the span.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping your anchor text inside the span and using CSS to underline that. One thing to keep in mind is that border is going to add to the elements height and will cause a "jumping" effect when you add/remove the border. I would go about making sure a border is always present, but "hidden" when it's being hovered over. You can do this by either using "transparent" as a color or match the color with the background hex value.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-rgb-6he0j

```
<p>
  <a href="#">
    <span>Link</span>
    <img src="imagePath" alt="logo" />
  </a>
</p>
```

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  position: relative;

  &, &:hover, span {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  }

  img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
  }

  &:hover span {
    border-bottom-color: red;
  }
}
```

EDIT: updated code formatting and added missing body styles